# Retrieve and Change Items in Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array of arrays in PHP representing vehicles:

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [VehicleClass] => Car 
        [IsNew] => 1 
        [Year] => 2016 
        [Make] => Cadillac 
        [Model] => ATS 
        [ModelCode] => 6AC69 
        [Trim] => 2.0L Turbo Luxury Collection 
        [Headline] => 2016 Cadillac ATS Luxury 
        [ImageList] => Array ( 
            [0] => http://example.com/01e8c76c1339f342837e7f085fa5984559849e54_large.jpeg 
            [1] => http://example.com/ef86b6a54888afa29d3bab8df74ee4d520c1b0cd_large.jpeg 
            [2] => http://example.com/50437892/c0c5177c707ac2fbf3a1bb087a067b51bfe4427b_large.jpeg 
            [3] => http://example.com/49067490d1ee673831df15413784cb1bb35b4142_large.jpeg 
            [4] => http://example.com/de12530a19cd38dd07942a8f3947debb4a64b0cf_large.jpeg 
        )
    )
)

    Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [VehicleClass] => Car 
        [IsNew] => 1 
        [Year] => 2016 
        [Make] => Cadillac 
        [Model] => ATS 
        [ModelCode] => 6AC69 
        [Trim] => 2.0L Turbo Luxury Collection 
        [Headline] => 2016 Cadillac ATS Luxury 
        [ImageList] => Array ( 
            [0] => http://example.com/01e8c76c1339f342837e7f085fa5984559849e54_large.jpeg 
            [1] => http://example.com/ef86b6a54888afa29d3bab8df74ee4d520c1b0cd_large.jpeg 
            [2] => http://example.com/50437892/c0c5177c707ac2fbf3a1bb087a067b51bfe4427b_large.jpeg 
            [3] => http://example.com/49067490d1ee673831df15413784cb1bb35b4142_large.jpeg 
            [4] => http://example.com/de12530a19cd38dd07942a8f3947debb4a64b0cf_large.jpeg 
        )
    )
)
```

I am trying to access the ImageList array, retrieve the URL to download the image, then change the URL. I have tried many different things, including many ideas from this site, but I feel like I am missing something simple.

The outer array is $aVehicle. So each of the vehicles in the examples above are represented by $aVehicle[0] and $aVehicle[1]. I need to loop through hundreds of them though.

Thanks for your help!

**Things I have tried:**

```
 foreach ($aVehicle as $vehicle => $data) {
    if(is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $title => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($title['ImageList'] as $imageNum => $imageURL) {
                    $imageURL = 'newURL.com';   
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**And**

```
foreach ($aVehicle as $vehicle => $data) {
    foreach ($data['ImageList'] as $imageURL) {
        $imageURL = 'newURL.com';   
    }
}
```

**And Now This**

I am able to access the value in the array, but I am not able to change it.

```
foreach ($aVehicle as $vehicle => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $title => $value) {
        if ( $title == 'ImageList' ) {
            foreach ($value as &$imageURL) {
                $imageURL = "newURL";
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are currently using to attempt this? It will help to clarify what you're trying to do and what needs to be changed to make it work.

Comment: I updated my post to include some examples of what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself. See the following code:

```
foreach ($aVehicle as $key => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $subkey => $value) {
        if ( $subkey == 'ImageList' ) {
            foreach ($value as $subsubkey => $imageURL) {
                $aVehicle[$key][$subkey][$subsubkey] = 'newURL.com';
            }
        }       
    }
}
```